# This site can’t be reached - refused to connect. - Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

No matter what I do I will always get this come up when trying to load the website. - (This site can’t be reached - 35.188.89.14 refused to connect.)

I've tried creating different instances using various methods. I am doing everything that I have always done but no matter what I'm stuck in receiving this.

I don't know where to turn or whats causing it, I'm completely stuck.

Comment: I know you're stuck but making multiple questions related to the same issue will not make you get more attention https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74009556/google-cloud-vm-insance-wordpress-bitnami-this-site-can-t-be-reached keep one and add details as needed

Comment: Please further clarify the problem that you are facing so that anyone can really help you instead of guessing.

Comment: I apologise, the problem is I don't know what to add because I'm still new to google cloud and it's theres not much to go off of. One minute my website was working and the next it came up with this error, nothing on google cloud was changed. What can I grab from google cloud and put on here that could help. I know theres not much that can be done without further information but I don't know what to provide.

Comment: Is the firewall configuration ok? As well, the IP is the same in the VM?

Comment: Thanks for your reply is there anyway to attach a image to this, I haven't changed anything in the firewall configuration and it all looks default. Also the ip is the same in the vm, as the record I've attached to the domain, if thats what you mean. Sorry as I've said I'm completely new

Comment: Hi @Corey try this step below 

1. Open GCP web console
2. Search Compute Engine
3. Locate your VM instance > Click your VM instance
4. Click Edit Button from the top
5. Locate "Networking" > Firewalls > Check 'Allow HTTP traffic' & Allow HTTPS traffic'
6. Save > Then try to browse again.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment of @Ferregina Pelona, I elaborate the configuration of the Firewall section configuration, you need to configure this firewall to permit HTTP or HTTPS traffic to the VM or instance, use this public document for [Create a VM instance from a public image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#publicimage)

@Corey Mason I know you're new to GCP so I tried to create a step by step how you configure the HTTP or HTTPS, and also you can use the link above for more details of the steps.

1. Open GCP web console
2. Search Compute Engine
3. Locate your VM instance > Click your VM instance
4. Click Edit Button from the top
5. Locate "Networking" > Firewalls > Check 'Allow HTTP traffic' & Allow HTTPS traffic'
6. Save > Then try to browse again.

Comment: Thank you Jeffery for taking the time to comment your detailed reply, fortunately the problem is all sorted now after various trial and error attempts. In the end I ended up changing my machine type from micro to small and it now seems to be able to handle it. Must of just been to small. I'm looking into changing to oracle cloud in the future, but not sure whats the better host. Many thanks.